# How can I make predictor variables into a matrix?

Tags: r, regression, matrix

How can I make predictor variables into a matrix?

if: formula = liking ~ moisture + sweetness

predictor variables are moisture and sweetness. now I want to calculate the coefficients by using Matrix calculation

```
b=solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
```

how can I define X as the matrix of the predictor variables? I need to do this in R.

Comment: " I need the R-code"  Sorry, SO is not a site designed to provide ready-to-use code.

Comment: are you overthinking this?  you can get the coefficients from `coef(liking)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You should include a minimal reproducible example so we don't have to supply one)

see `?model.matrix`

Here I compute X'X for a data set that comes with R

```
 x <- model.matrix(dist~speed,cars)
 crossprod(x)
            (Intercept) speed
(Intercept)          50   770
speed               770 13228
```